# How to create a skeletonframe from a self-created skeleton, not from kinect data

Tags: c#, kinect

I have successfully created a skeleton by saving data to a file and reading it out again, the issue that i now face is to add this skeleton to the skeletons[] array. Normally you'd directly add the data to the array from the skeletonframe (created by kinect as it reads data) by using frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons). Now I face the problem of not having a frame since I created data myself, any ideas as to how I can solve this problem?

Comment: How are you saving data out and reading it back in; how is the data formatted?  Have you looked at Kinect Toolbox (http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/), which has a Skeleton recorder?

Comment: I was trying to do it my own way which didn't work out so well, using the toolbox now and it seems to solve my problem :)